# Search condition with a reference like a join

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

in a project I just joined, they have 2 schemas: players et users, a player reference 2 users with objectIds.

```
const player = new Schema({
    name: string,
    best: {
        friendId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
    },
    worst: {
        enemyId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
    }
})

const user = new Schema({
    name: string
})
```

We would like to be able to search the players by just entering a name but it can be the name of the player or the name of any user referenced.
Can this be done with mongoose using a single query ?